# Null pointer Exception in Broadcast receiver while accessing DB

Tags: android

i want to access phone number from my DB in Broadcast receiver to compare with message address i got null pointer exception in SMSlockDB and SMsReciver class i point out that also in my code because Data base does not open i also check my method in other activities it work correctly the phone number also save in Data Base 
here  is my code

```
public class SmsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

SQLiteDatabase database;
//Context c;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // ---get the SMS message passed in---
     SmslockDB no = new SmslockDB(context);

    database = context.openOrCreateDatabase(SmslockDB.DATABASE_NAME, 0, null);

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String adrrs = "";
        String msbdy = "";
        String messages = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) 
 pdus[i]);
 adrrs += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress().toString().trim();
        msbdy += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString().trim();
        String rmspno = adrrs.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        String cmpno = no.Spclgetno(rmspno);<------------ here my loggate  
                                                                          show error

                if (rmspno.contains(cmpno)) {

                    messages += "SMS from " + n + " :\n";
                    messages += msbdy + "\n";

                    try {

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // ---display the new SMS message--
        Toast.makeText(context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    this.abortBroadcast();

                }
            }

        }
    }
       }
```

here is my DB

```
public class SmslockDB {

//  tabel columns
public static final String ROWID_PRF = " _id";
public static final String PRF_NO = "_noto";
public static final String PRF_NAME = "_name";

//  DB Name
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SMSlock_DB";
//  DB version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1 ;
    // table 1 name 
private static final String TABLE_PROFILE = "T_SProle";   // second table name

private DbHelper ourhelper;
private Context ourcontext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourdatabase;
public static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public Context context;
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MSSG +"(" +
                ROWID_SM + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                SMS_NO + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                SMS_Body + " TEXT NOT NULL );"
                );
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PROFILE +"(" +
                ROWID_PRF + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                PRF_NO + " TEX NOT NULL, " +
                PRF_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL );"
                );  
       }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MSSG);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PROFILE);
        onCreate(db);

    }
    }
 public SmslockDB(Context c) {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    ourcontext = c;
}
 public SmslockDB open() throws SQLException{

ourhelper = new DbHelper(ourcontext);
ourdatabase = ourhelper.getWritableDatabase();
return this;
 }
 public void close(){
ourhelper.close();
}
// method that i want to receive in BroadcastReciever 
public String Spclgetno(String spno)  throws SQLException{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String[] columns = new String[] {ROWID_PRF, PRF_NO, PRF_NAME };
//ourdatabase = ourhelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c = ourdatabase.query(TABLE_PROFILE, columns,  PRF_NO + "='" + spno + "'",  
    null, null, null, null);<------- also in this line query show exception

if(c != null && c.moveToFirst() ) {     //&& c.getCount() > 0



    String retsno = c.getString(1);
    Log.i("prfno", retsno.toString());
    return retsno;
}
return null;
  }
```

here is my loggate

```
 04-10 15:06:14.923: W/dalvikvm(29010): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught   
 exception (group=0x41f852a0)
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   
 start receiver com.smslocker.SmsReciever: java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):   at   
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2269)
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):   at   
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:134)
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):   at    
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):   at    
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):   at     
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):   at   
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):   at   
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):   at   
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):   at  
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):   at   
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):   at   
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):   at    
 com.smslocker.SmslockDB.Spclgetno(SmslockDB.java:109)
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):   at   
 com.smslocker.SmsReciever.onReceive(SmsReciever.java:51)
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):   at    
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2262)
 04-10 15:06:14.943: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):   ... 10 more
 04-10 15:06:15.003: W/CursorWrapperInner(29010): Cursor finalized without prior close()
 04-10 15:06:15.003: D/dalvikvm(29010): GC_CONCURRENT freed 311K, 13% free   
 10230K/11719K, paused 12ms+5ms, total 111ms
```

i regester in example like that

```
   <receiver
        android:name="com.smslocker.SmsReciever"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: What is line number 109 in `SmslockDB.java` and line number 51 in `SmsReciever.java`?

Comment: Seems like the SmslockDB object is null. Can you confirm it?

Comment: String cmpno = no.Spclgetno(rmspno);   this line in SmsReceaver class also i point it like <-------- that

Comment: Cursor c = ourdatabase.query(TABLE_PROFILE, columns,  PRF_NO + "='" + spno + "'",  
    null, null, null, null); this line in SmslockDB.java

Comment: @Aashish yes i know that but i need soloution for that

Comment: @Aashish what can i do now its null

Comment: check your `ourdatabase` object. It seems that `ourdatabase` object is null